# How to dynamically import React JSX Component; SyntaxError: Unexpected Token

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app, dynamic-import

How can I dynamically import a file containing JSX and have it be transpiled like a regular import?

I'm trying to dynamically `import()` this React component:

```
import React from 'react';

export default () => {
  return (
    <div>Test</div>
  );
}
```

from a service in my application:

```
import('./test').then(({default: Component}) => {
  callback(Component);
});
```

but it appears the dynamic import doesn't transpile the JSX:

> SyntaxError: /path/to/test.js: Unexpected token (5:4)
>
> ```
> 3 | export default () => {
> 4 |   return (
> 5 |     <div>Test</div>
>   |     ^
> 6 |   );
> 7 | }
> 8 |
> ```

I have plenty of regular imports which work fine:

```
import OtherComponent from './OtherComponent';

export default () => (
  <OtherComponent />
);
```

so Babel is definitely transpiling those... just not the dynamic ones.

Looking at the build output from `yarn build`, I can see a chunk is created but it simply contains this error (implying the file cannot be transpiled at build time ?!?):

```
(window["webpackJsonptest-app"]=window["webpackJsonptest-app"]||[]).push([[0],{272:function(m,e){throw new Error('Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):\nSyntaxError: /path/to/build/test.js: Unexpected token (12:2) ... etc
```

Comment: the code looks ok, the `@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import` should be part of `@babel/preset-env`. What's your `presets` in babel config?

Comment: @XPX-Gloom just `env` yeah.. a standard create-react-app that I haven't ejected from

Comment: Try returning `React.createElement()` instead of `jsx` and see if that works. Seems like jsx isn't being treated as an element when imported this way. https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#createelement

Comment: @AlexMcMillan I assume you should also have `preset-react` since you mentioned that regular imports of React component works. I'd recommend creating a most basic test case to see what Babel/Webpack config you are missing